# HTML5 <br> does not seem to be working

Tags: html

I am a bit bewildered, the HTML br to insert a new line does not seem to be working. The browser (Chrome) is interpreting it as a literal. This is plain HTML and I would have thought that the 
 tag will be given its special meaning by the browser. The image is attached.

[image: HTML5 br not working]

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a jsFiddle?

Comment: Have you tried using `<br/>` instead?

Comment: In what editor/software did you add those `<br>`s? It seems not like a HTML-enabled environment therefore those tags were escaped. Can you show us the source code of your HTML?

Comment: thats chrome developers console. Will it not work. I copied the code to jsfiddle and the br tag got decoded like: "1 Allerton Branch Way &lt;br&gt; Bradford &lt;br&gt; XX10 1XX". Now if I replace &lt;br&gt; with <br> in jsfiddle it works but not sure why it is not working when I edit html in developers console

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6uz41xjs/

Comment: Yes if you edit them directly from the developer tool you are actually editing the _text being displayed_, not its HTML source code. Try right click and choose "Edit as HTML" from the contextual menu instead.

Comment: @user2611292 please dont force us to guess, post your source code in your question.

Comment: @renfei thats what i did

Comment: banana : whats there to guess??? the html is shown in the image and in the jsfiddle . have a look

Comment: @renfei: perhaps i was not doing that. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must be using `XHTML`, where there are some compatibility issues using bare `<br>` tag. I suggest to use `<br />`. Moreover editing html in developers console is not sufficient, you need to edit the source code.

More views on bare 
 tag are discussed in here https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/br-vs-br.90410/